# Trouble on deleting "associated" model instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, callback, associations

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and I would like to know why database records in the following example are not deleted on destroying an "associated" model instance.

In my application I have these classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account,
    :autosave    => true,
    :dependent   => :destroy

  has_many :article_relationships,
    :class_name  => 'ArticleUserRelationship',
    :foreign_key => 'user_id',
    :autosave    => true,
    :dependent   => :destroy
  has_many :articles,
    :through     => :article_relationships,
    :source      => :article,
    :dependent   => :destroy

  ...
end

class ArticleRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  ...
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user,
    :autosave     => true,
    :dependent    => :destroy
end
```

If I run `@article.user.destroy` or `@article.user.account.destroy` methods (note: `article` is kind of `Article`) those will delete from the database the *user*, the *account* and *article relationship* records but will not delete users related *articles*, even if I state `has_many :articles ... :dependent => :destroy`.

Anyway I read the official [RoR guide about the "has_many Association Reference"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference) and at the *4.3.2.6 :dependent* chapter it says:

> This option (`:dependent`) is ignored when you use the :through option on the association.

**So, what could/should I make in order to delete all user `articles`? That is, what method could/should I run? How?**

Comment: That looks like it should work. Try simplifying the code to experiment. I would remove the account association from user and also simplify the association between User and Comment (you don't need to specify class_name and foreign_key. Then see if @user.destroy deletes their comments. Also make sure your migrations have run and the appropriate associations work (user.comments should return them)

Comment: @lebreeze - You have right. *However* I updated the question with my "real" problem. Sorry, I was wrong!